# Multiple commands using batch and Plink?

Tags: ssh, putty, plink

Hello I am trying to use a batch file to log into a server using plink, go to specific directory and run commands. I can not get this to work. Appreciate any help.

```
plink -t -ssh root@111.111.111.111 -pw xxxxx
cd /home/wonderd/public_html/dev.xxxx.com
./shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_price
```

Comment: That is little enough text that you can and should paste it into your question.

Comment: I usually have issues trying to format code when posting so its easier to understand if you can see it on the actual notepad

Comment: I did not create that other post.

Answer (score 9):

First I think you have to write the machine name or IP after the plink call
The second issue is that `plink` run always from root directory so you have to send couple commands together separated by `;`

like this :

```
plink.exe <full name of machine / IP> "command one; command 2"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
plink root@192.168.0.1 -pw xxxx (cd /home/path to script ; ./script.sh)
```